# How to generate an iPhone XCTest report?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have to develop one iPhone application and I have used XCTest for unit testing.

I have done successfully XCTest unit testing but I want to generate reports of XCTest unit testing in an Excel file. How do I do this?

Comment: Were you expecting someone to (write a script to) generate a report from test results? If so, perhaps you could look at the results data, then edit your question to provide details about the type of report (detailed breakdown? pass/fail summary?) that you want.  You may also want to specify whether you're looking for a .CSV that you import, or an automated solution that creates or maintains an Excel file for you.

Answer (score 0):

Test reports are no longer generated for XCTest results.

You'll have to parse the build log, or the individual test results, which you can find at

> /Users/<User>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<Product Identifier>/TestResults/<Timestamp>.xctestresults/results.plist

If you are using Xcode Server Continuous Integration, you can find the Bot results at

> /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Latest/output/xcodebuild_result.bundle/Info.plist